# Unused Import Statement - Warning message

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Getting a warning message for below import statement:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

WARNING MESSAGE:
"This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing , this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items."
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pyr1m.jpg)

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep


class Login(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get("https://gwl.greatwestlife.com/MyLogin")
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        sleep(4)

    def test_user_can_login(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='loginPage:loginForm:username']").clear()
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='loginPage:loginForm:username']").send_keys("#####")
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='loginPage:loginForm:password']").send_keys("#####")
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='loginPage:loginForm:loginButton']").click()

    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        self.driver.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Warning message "This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing , this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items."

Can someone please educate me why am I getting this warning message and how to get rid of this error message so that statement is not greyed out?

Comment: Did you google the error message? That's the first thing you should do and then try the solutions there and see what works. If nothing works, then come back and edit your question, add what you tried and what the result was.

Comment: I tried google but I am not getting clear answers that is why I posted the question here.

Comment: you imported `Keys` class, but never used it... either use it in your code or remove the import line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code example you are importing the Keys class which you have never used in your code.. PyCharm is trying to notice you that you have imported the Keys class but you haven't used it **(Unused import statement )** so in this case you have two choices :

- The first one  : if are not willing nor going to use the Keys class in
  your code then you can simply delete the import
- The second : if you are going to use it in your code
  later, then this will automatically disappear once you use the Keys class, and the import statement will not be greyed out

**Note** that the Keys class provide special keys in the keyboard for example : RETURN, F1, ALT .. etc 
you can read this explained example from [selenium documentation on readthedocs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage)

Comment: I have used "send_keys" method for the username and password. Please look at the code.

Comment: i did read the code , send_keys method is used to send values but the Keys is another  class and it is used for the special keys like RETURN , F1 , ALT , TAB etc as i mentioned above , let's say i want to send RETURN value then i will do something like  : `self.driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)` , i know this might be a little confusing but just remember that Keys is a different class and used for special keys values . i hope this did help

Comment: you can read the Keys class code here https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/common/keys.py and i hope that the Keys class and what it does will be clear to you .